# Can you commit an existing working copy to a new branch using TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've got a working copy that I checkout of the trunk and I have made quite a few changes and would prefer to commit back to a branch instead of the trunk (from which is was checked out from).

Is this possible and how can I do this using TortoiseSVN?

Comment: Do you want to create a new branch or commit to an existing branch?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Select *Branch/tag...* and select the *working copy* radio button,

Answer (score 4):

Use the Switch feature to direct your working copy to your desired branch.  Then your commit will go to the branch rather than trunk.